# Интеграция телефонного вызова через интернет

Tags: алгоритм, php

Подскажите, какие у Вас есть идеи для реализации следующего:

У меня есть телефон. Его необходимо интегрировать с сетью, чтобы я с другого компьютера мог совершать вызовы, таким образом чтобы звук передавался на компьютер.
И совершать вызовы я тоже мог удаленно. 
(Соответственно потом внедрить запись разговоров и прочее)

Для начала хотя бы научиться передавать номер с сайта на телефон, и он локально совершал вызов. Чтобы я не тратил время на набор номера.

Comment: Наверное, нужно найти SDK или php class для работы с телефоном из-под вашей серверной OS.

Comment: напишите для андроида программу, которая будет слушать пуш-нотификации от Вашего сайта. Когда нужно совершить звонок, сайт посылает нотификацию (внутри будет и телефон записан), а телефон собственно совершает звонок.

С записью звонков будет немного сложенее. Не все андроиды так просто разрешают делать запись.

Comment: KoVadim, т.е. передавать голос на сайт и там производить запись тоже не получится?

Comment: проблема не в том, что андроид не может сделать собственно запись в файл, а в том, что не так просто получить собственно этот звук. Но с другой стороны, кто мешает подключить гарнитуру и делать запись с компа. Но, думаю, это уже другая история.